# JS pushing arrays to array (concat) in apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Note this is not a duplicate of [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating) because I'm looking to have a nested array, not to simply extend an array with another array to result into 1 array. Please read the question properly before you mark this as duplicate.

I'm looping through rows in a (Google) sheet to collect values, and would like to add each row as array to an array, which should result in an output like this (simplified example to illustrate):

array_main = [[row1_cell1,row1_cell2,row1_cell3], [row2_cell1,row2_cell2,row2_cell3], ...]

I first tried this with .push, which adds the values, but not as array:

```js
accounts_last_row = 10
accounts_array = []

for (var i = 0; i < accounts_last_row; ++i) {
  if ((accounts_range[i][1] == 'test') {
    accounts_array.push([ [accounts_range[i][1]],[accounts_range[i][2]] ])
  }
}
```

I'm aware similar questions have been asked, but most of them simply recommend using .concat to merge 2 arrays. I tried this as well but it doesn't add anything to the array:

```js
...
if ((accounts_range[i][1] == 'test') {
    accounts_array.concat( [accounts_range[i][1]],[accounts_range[i][2]] )
  }
...
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend an existing JavaScript array with another array, without creating a new array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374126/how-to-extend-an-existing-javascript-array-with-another-array-without-creating)

Comment: different use case, your link aims to have a single array (not nested) output.

Comment: The idea applies. `.push.apply` is my point.

Comment: what exact syntax are you proposing? If I simply use it as in the other question, my array stays empty: accounts_array.push.apply( [accounts_range[i][1],accounts_range[i][2]] )

Comment: I wrote an answer which demonstrates what I intended you to get from the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, inner arrays are simple ones, you had too many brackets.

Try like this:

`accounts_array.push( [accounts_range[i][1],accounts_range[i][2]] );`

the code above will work to add rows.
If you want to add data as a single column the you will have to change the brackets like this:

`accounts_array.push( [accounts_range[i][1]],[accounts_range[i][2]] );`

Comment: thought so too and tried that as well, but still doesn't return the nested array. At leats that's what I'm seeing in the apps script log file. Could this be a problem with the apps script logger that it doesn't show the nested arrays? Log output is as follows: accounts_array: test,96145912,test,37275407,test,127772724 (I'm expecting accounts_array: [test,96145912],[test,37275407],[test,127772724]

Comment: Use JSON.Stringify(value) to see the structure. I'm sure this is the right way, use it all the time ;)

Comment: Do you mean in the log or how do I use that in apps script?

Comment: Logger.log(JSON.Stringify(value))

Comment: I assume by 'value' you mean the 'accounts_array'? It results in an error: TypeError: Cannot find function Stringify in object [object JSON].

Comment: I'm typing this on a phone, please use control+space on your keyboard to activate the autocomplete feature.  JSON.  and at the dot press CTRL SPACE you will see all the available methods with the right spelling.  Sorry about that

Comment: You should not be using `Logger` to look at complex data! Either pause at a breakpoint or use `console` with Stackdriver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51582449/utilities-parsecsvcsv-also-splits-on-commas/51582684#51582684

Comment: @tealowpillow the correct spelling has no Capital in 'stringify' indeed, stupid phone... @ tehhowch that's also a manner indeed, but it's mainly a question of habit.

Comment: thanks, stringify works now, but confirms that it's still one array (instead of nested): [18-08-23 14:27:59:281 BST] [["test"],[96145912],["test"],[37275407],["test"],[127772724]]

Comment: This answer(`accounts_array.push( [accounts_range[i][1],accounts_range[i][2]] );`) should work. You must be doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: What you are showing is obviously an array of arrays, aka nested arrays... Write it to a sheet to verify it works fine.

Comment: @Sergeinsas yes it's an array of arrays, but not what I am aiming for. I'm aiming for this: [["test",96145912],["test",37275407],["test",127772724]]

Comment: got it! the damn brackets... accounts_array.push([accounts_range[i][1],accounts_range[i][2]])

Comment: that's why it's accepted :). The (normal) log still shows it as one array, that's were the confusion started. Tried the json log with all options but the most obvious one...

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation can be done neatly with `Array#filter` and `Array#push` and `apply`:

```
const results = [];
const colIndexToTest = /** 0, 1, etc. */;
const requiredValue = /** something */;
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(
  function (sheet, sheetIndex) {
    var matchedRows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(
      function (row, rowIndex) {
        // Return true if this is a row we want.
        return row[colIndexToTest] === requiredValue;
      });
    if (matchedRows.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(results, matchedRows);
  });
// Use Stackdriver to view complex objects properly.
console.log({message: "matching rows from all sheets", results: results});
```

The above searches the given column of all rows on all sheets for the given value, and collects it into a 2d array. If all rows are the same number of columns, this array would be directly serializable with `Range#setValues`.

This code could have used `map` instead of `forEach` and the `push.apply`, but that would place empty or undefined elements for sheet indexes that had no matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming if account-range[i][1] is 'test' copy the entire row to accounts_array.  Drop the second index.

```
accounts_last_row = 10
accounts_array = []

for (var i = 0; i < accounts_last_row; ++i) {
  if ((accounts_range[i][1] == 'test') {
    accounts_array.push(accounts_range[i])
  }
}
```